# Rayleigh quotient iteration error estimate

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ real symmetric matrix and let $U$ and $D$ be such that $A = UDU^t$ and $D$ is the diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $A$.
>
> Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector such that $||x|| = 1$, where $|| \cdot ||$ is the norm induced by the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x$ approximates an eigenvector $u$ of $A$. Let $\mu = \langle Ax, x\rangle$ be the corresponding Rayleigh quotient. How can we prove that $$|\lambda - \mu| \leq ||Ax - \mu x||, $$ where $Au = \lambda u$ ?

I know that $$||Ax - \mu x|| = ||DU^tx - \mu U^t x||, $$ but I don't know how to further relate this inequality to $|\lambda - \mu|.$